# i want to connect two circle by line while the circle moves in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to connect two circle by line while the circle moves:

**The Code (http://codepen.io/bala0708/pen/XNEmeO):**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var p = $("#c1");
  var positionx = p.position();
  var c1left = positionx.left;
  var x1 = c1left + 50;
  var c1top = positionx.top;
  var x2 = c1top + 50;

  var p1 = $("#c2");
  var positiony = p1.position();
  var c2left = positiony.left;
  var y1 = c2left + 50;
  var c2top = positiony.top;
  var y2 = c2top + 50;

  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var a = 50;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,x2);
  ctx.lineTo(y1,y2);
  ctx.stroke();

});
```

```css
#c1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid red;
  left:50px;
  position:absolute;
} 
#c2{  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:100px;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px);
} 
#mydiv{
  width:500px;
  height:700px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="c1"></div>
  <div id="c2" class=" "></div>
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: added snippet and reformat question

Comment: How will the circle be moving?